# Can I not specify start/end for a paused ADF pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have two ADF pipelines using the same dataset. I want the first pipeline to be paused until I want to use it later. I deployed pipeline1 using

```
"isPaused" : "true"
```

If I try to deploy it with  `"start"` and `"end"` properties, the deploying fails as I get the error

```
Entity provisioning failed: Cannot set active period Start=05/11/2018 06:00:00, End=12/31/9991 23:59:59 for pipeline 'Pipeline1' due to conflicts on Output: Output1 with Pipeline: Pipeline2, Activity Activity1, Period: Start=05/11/2018 06:00:00, End=01/01/9992 00:00:00 Output: Output2 with Pipeline: Pipeline2, Activity3, Period: Start=05/11/2018 06:00:00, End=01/01/9992 00:00:00 Output: Output3 with Pipeline: Pipeline2, Period: Start=05/11/2018 06:00:00, End=01/01/9992 00:00:00 . Try changing the active period or using autoResolve option when setting the active period.
```

I just want to know if skipping the `"start"` and `"end"` properties cause any errors anywhere.

I'll have to look for another approach to solve the conflict then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want to take a look at execute pipeline activity. It could invoke another pipeline inside a pipeline. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-execute-pipeline-activity